# Regex is trying to avoid "Not matching" and always matching

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a regex to check messages related to delivery(supply) issues. 
The regex i am using is `\b(problem(s|)|issue(s|)) (([^\n \.]*? ){1,3}?)(suppl(y|ies)|parcel|deliver(y|))\b` where `(([^\n \.]*? ){0,3}?)` acts like a window of 1 to 3 words

This matches with the following text:

1. have never had **issues with supply** delivery or service
2. have never had a **problem with the delivery**
3. too many **problems with getting my supplies**

The problem is that the first 2 texts have a preceding `never` which I want to handle.

I tried using negative lookahead and used the the following changes to my regex `\b(?!never)((?:[^\n \.]+? ){2,2}?)(problem(s|)|issue(s|)) (([^\n \.]*? ){1,3}?)(suppl(y|ies)|parcel|deliver(y|))\b` which doesn't match with the 1st text but matches with the 2nd and 3rd texts

The regex `\b(?!never)((?:[^\n \.]+? ){3,3}?)(problem(s|)|issue(s|)) (([^\n \.]*? ){1,3}?)(suppl(y|ies)|parcel|deliver(y|))\b` matches with 1st and 3rd and does not match with the 2nd text.

After combining these 2 regex `\b(?!never)((?:[^\n \.]+? ){2,3}?)(problem(s|)|issue(s|)) (([^\n \.]*? ){1,3}?)(suppl(y|ies)|parcel|deliver(y|))\b` all 3 texts are matched.

So basically when `never` is the 2nd word before the original match, the regex takes a window of 3 words and matches and when `never` is the 3rd word before the original match, the regex takes a window of 2 and matches.

The matches are as follows:

1. **have never had issues with supply** delivery or service
2. have never **had a problem with the delivery**
3. **too many problems with getting my supplies**

It is as if the regex tries to  always match where ever possible.
[Link to example](https://regex101.com/r/H8Dwpx/1)

Is this the general behaviour of regex?

Also, is there a way this problem can be tackled?

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using it in .NET, use `(?<!\bnever\b.*?)\b(problems?|issues?) ((?:[^\n .]*? ){1,3}?)(suppl(?:y|ies)|parcels?|deliver(?:y|ies))\b`

Comment: i am using it for python and i have tried negative lookbehind patters but getting the error `a quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width`

Comment: Then use it with PyPi `regex` module. It supports variable-width lookbehinds as .NET does. [See how it will work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cbnever%5cb.*%3f%29%5cb%28problems%3f%7cissues%3f%29+%28%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%5cn+.%5d*%3f+%29%7b1%2c3%7d%3f%29%28suppl%28%3f%3ay%7cies%29%7cparcels%3f%7cdeliver%28%3f%3ay%7cies%29%29%5cb&i=have+never+had+issues+with+supply+delivery+or+service%0d%0a%0d%0ahave+never+had+a+problem+with+the+delivery%0d%0a%0d%0atoo+many+problems+with+getting+my+supplies).

Comment: ok will try that and let you know